# Find all real numbers $x$ for which $\frac{8^x+27^x}{12^x+18^x}=\frac76$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, contest-math

Find all real numbers $x$ for which $$\frac{8^x+27^x}{12^x+18^x}=\frac76$$

I have tried to fiddle with it as follows:

$$2^{3x} \cdot 6 +3^{3x} \cdot 6=12^x \cdot 7+18^x \cdot 7$$
$$ 3 \cdot 2^{3x+1}+ 2 \cdot 3^{3x+1}=7 \cdot 6^x(2^x+3^x)$$
Dividing both sides by $6$ gives us
$$2^{3x}+3^{3x}=7 \cdot 6^{x-1}(2^x+3^x)$$

Is this helpful? If so, how should I proceed form here? If not any hints would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please, make titles more informative and less subjective.

Comment: Ok, I'll make sure I do that in future

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Let us put $2^x=a,3^x=b$ to remove the indices to improve clarity

So, $8^x=(2^3)^x=(2^x)^3=a^3$  and similarly, $27^x=b^3$

$12^x=(2^2\cdot3)^x=(2^x)^2\cdot3^x=a^2b$ and similarly, $18^x=ab^2$

So, the problem reduces to $$\frac{a^3+b^3}{ab(a+b)}=\frac76$$

$\displaystyle\implies 6(a^2-ab+b^2)=7ab$ as $a+b\ne0$

$\displaystyle\implies 6\left(\frac ab\right)^2-13\cdot\frac ab+6=0$

$\displaystyle\implies \frac ab=\frac32$ or $\dfrac23$

So, $\displaystyle\left(\frac23\right)^x=\frac32$ or $\dfrac23$

If $\displaystyle\left(\frac23\right)^x=\frac32\implies\left(\frac23\right)^x=\left(\frac23\right)^{-1}\iff\left(\frac23\right)^{x+1}=1$

Similarly, if $\displaystyle\left(\frac23\right)^x=\frac23, \left(\frac23\right)^{x-1}=1 $

Now if $\displaystyle u^m=1,$

either $\displaystyle m=0,u\ne0; $

or $\displaystyle u=1$

or $\displaystyle u=-1,m$ is even

Comment: Thanks so much that's really neat!

Comment: @JohnMarty, my pleasure. Replacement of numbers with indices by algebraic symbol  sometimes helps clarity

Comment: Yeah, when I tried it it looked pretty bewildering, your method simplifies it immeasurably :)

Comment: @lab-bhattacharjee, I'd say your comment ("Replacement of numbers with indices by algebraic symbol sometimes helps clarity") would go well at the top of your reply. It would help to give context to the solution method, making it less of a 'magical' thing and more of a 'technique'

Comment: @RolazaroAzeveires, how about the edited version?

Comment: @lab-bhattacharjee, better I think (2 weeks latter I alredy do not recall the initial version..) I probably would go as far as clarifying upfront that the choice of bases 2 and 3 are because they are the prime factors in 8, 12, and so on; but I guess that is clear enough from the immediate development (and thanks)

Answer (score 6):

$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
6(8^x + 27^x) &=& 7(12^x + 18^x) \\
6(2^{3x} + 3^{3x}) &=& 7(3^x2^{2x} + 3^{2x}2^x) \\
\end{array}
$$

Substitute $a\!=\!2^x$ and $b\!=\!3^x$ for simplicity:

$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
6(a^3 + b^3) &=& 7(a^2b + ab^2) \\
6(a+b)(a^2 - ab + b^2) &=& 7ab(a+b) \\
6(a^2 - ab + b^2) &=& 7ab \\
6a^2 -13ab + 6b^2 &=& 0 \\
a^2 -\frac{13}{6}ab + b^2 &=& 0
\end{array}
$$

The left hand side can be factorized as $\left(a-\dfrac{3}{2}b\right)\left(a-\dfrac{2}{3}b\right)$.

$$
\left(a-\dfrac{3}{2}b\right)\left(a-\dfrac{2}{3}b\right)=0 \\
\begin{array}{rclcrcl}
2a &=& 3b &\text{or}& 3a &=& 2b \\
2.2^x &=& 3.3^x &\qquad\text{or}\qquad& 3.2^x &=& 2.3^x \\
x &=& -1 &\qquad\text{or}\qquad& x &=& +1
\end{array}
$$

Therefore, $x$ can be either $-1$ or $+1$.

$$ \boxed{x = \mp 1} $$

Answer (score 0):

$\Rightarrow $ $6(8^x+27^x)=7(12^x+18^x)$

Divide by$12^x$

$\Rightarrow $$ 6((\frac{2}{3}) ^x+(\frac{3}{2})^{2x}) =7(1+(\frac{3}{2})^{x})$

$\Rightarrow $ $(\frac{2}{3}) ^x+(\frac{3}{2})^{2x}-\frac{7}{6}-(\frac{7}{6})(\frac{3}{2}) ^x=0$

We put :$t=(\frac{3}{2}) ^x$

$\Rightarrow $ $\frac{1}{t} +t^2 - \frac{7}{6}t-\frac{7}{6}=0$

Multiply by $t$

$\Rightarrow $ $ 1+t^3 - \frac{7}{6}t^2-\frac{7}{6} t=0$

We can see $-1$ is a solution of the equation

So:after division by $t+1$ we see

$ t^2 - \frac{13}{6}x+1=0$

$\triangle =(\frac{13}{6})^2 - 4=(\frac{5}{6}) ^2 $

So :

$t_1=\frac{\frac{13}{6}+\frac{5}{6}}{2}=\frac{3}{2} =(\frac{3}{2})^{x_1} $

$\Rightarrow $ $x_1=1$

And

$t_2=\frac{\frac{13}{6}-\frac{5}{6}}{2}=\frac{2}{3}=(\frac{3}{2})^{x_2} $

$\Rightarrow $ $x_2=-1$

Finally

$x=-1$ or $ x= 1$