# Solve $ \left(\sqrt[3]{4-\sqrt{15}}\right)^x+\left(\sqrt[3]{4+\sqrt{15}}\right)^x=8 $

Tags: roots, square-numbers

I don't know what can I substitute for $x$ so that equation becomes satisfied. Any assistance will be greatly valued.

Thanks!

Comment: you see a third root in both TerMs. Can you do anything with that?

Comment: Sure you have no idea about a specific value of $x$ which would achieve miracles? Absolutely sure?

Comment: Distant relative : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/384090/find-all-real-numbers-x-for-which-frac8x27x12x18x-frac76

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use $A=4+\sqrt{15}$. That'll give you $A^{-1}=\dfrac{1}{4+\sqrt{15}}=\dfrac{4-\sqrt{15}}{16-15}=4-\sqrt{15}$

The equation then becomes,

$$A^{x/3}+A^{-x/3}=8\implies (A^{x/3})^2-8A^{x/3}+1=0$$

Solve this quadratic in terms of $A^{x/3}$ using the quadratic formula and you'll get,

$$A^{x/3}=\frac{8\pm\sqrt{64-4}}{2}=\frac{8\pm2\sqrt{15}}{2}=4\pm\sqrt{15}\\ \implies (4+\sqrt{15})^{x/3}=(4+\sqrt{15})^{\pm 1}\\ \implies \frac{x}{3}=\pm 1 \implies x=\pm 3$$

Comment: @AleksXPO, if my answer helped you, you can accept it by clicking on the check mark beside my answer. :)

Comment: Yes, I'll do that, however I have to wait a few more minutes until the system let's me accept an answer.

Comment: Do you see how else you could see +-3 is the solution?

Comment: Of course @PrasunBiswas has answered you greatly in a very short time. It is his right that you accept his answer :)

Comment: Yes, 1/3*3 = 1, so the root is gone in both parenthesis, and 4+4 = 8.

Comment: @wowlolbrommer, a nice approach to this problem is to note the symmetry of solutions. If $x=\alpha$ is a solution, $x=(-\alpha)$ is a solution too. Establishing the symmetry argument is trivial, I guess. And it is almost obvious that $x=3$ is a solution. By the argument of symmetry, $x=(-3)$ will also be a solution.

Comment: it is the same approach as mine

Answer (score 7):

Hint: $$\sqrt[3]{4-\sqrt{15}}\cdot \sqrt[3]{4+\sqrt{15}}=1$$
from here we get $$t^x+\frac{1}{t^x}=8$$

Comment: That isn't needed

Comment: hm and why? with this hint you can solve your problem, but thanks for downvoting

Comment: I did not downvote.

Comment: my comment was deleted

Comment: I didn't down-vote either.

Comment: I, however, voted up @Doctor!

Answer (score 0):

$$4-\sqrt{15}=t^3,\sqrt{15}=4-t^3$$
$$4+\sqrt{15}=8-t^3$$
$$(\sqrt[3]{8-t^3})^x=8-t^x$$
$$(8-t^3)^{\frac{x}{3}}=8-t^x$$
$$(8-t^3)^x=(8-t^x)^3$$
$x=3$ obviousley is a solution