# How to solve $16^x-10\cdot4^x+16=0$

Tags: quadratics

I am unsure how to go about solving this equation to find x. Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Set $4^x = y$, then what is $16^x$ in terms of $y$?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1356236/what-is-the-solution-to-the-equation-9x-6x-2-cdot-4x-0   https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/384090/find-all-real-numbers-x-for-which-frac8x27x12x18x-frac76   https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1330422/how-to-solve-this-equation-for-x-left-sqrt2-sqrt3-rightx-left-sq   https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1237837/solve-left-sqrt34-sqrt15-rightx-left-sqrt34-sqrt15-right

Comment: It's a quadratic equation in disguise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $4^x=t$, then $16^x=(4^x)^2=t^2$

So, your equation will be 
$$t^2-10t+16=0$$ which is a simple quadratic equation.

Solve for $t$ first and then solve for $x$  ($\because 4^x=t $)