# $ (5+2\sqrt6)^{\sin x} +(5-2\sqrt6)^{\sin x} = 2\sqrt3 $ , where $ 0 ≤ x≤ 360 $

Tags: algebra-precalculus, problem-solving

There is something I haven't picked up on, a hint would be appreciated

Given that $(\sqrt3+\sqrt2)^2 = (5+2\sqrt6)$ and $ (\sqrt3-\sqrt2)^2 = (5-2\sqrt6)$

Find the values of x
for which$
(5+2\sqrt6)^{\sin x}
+(5-2\sqrt6)^{\sin x}
= 2\sqrt3 $
, where $
0
0
≤ x≤ 360
$

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1330422/how-to-solve-this-equation-for-x-left-sqrt2-sqrt3-rightx-left-sq  or https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1237837/solve-left-sqrt34-sqrt15-rightx-left-sqrt34-sqrt15-right?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Use that $$(5+2\sqrt{6})(5-2\sqrt{6})=1$$
Then you will get $$(5+2\sqrt{6})^{\sin(x)}+\frac{1}{(5+2\sqrt{6})^{\sin(x)}}=2\sqrt{3}$$

Comment: is that first = supposed to be a + ?

Comment: It is an equal sign, multiply it out, $$25-24=1$$

Comment: no sorry in the second equation is that supposed to be a "=" after the first part

Comment: No it must be a plus sign, a typo sorry

Comment: Then I just finish it like with the quadratic formula im assuming

Comment: Yes it will be a quadratic equation