# How to solve this equation for $x$?$\left(\sqrt{2-\sqrt{3}}\right)^x + \left(\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3}}\right)^x = 2$

Tags: exponentiation, radicals

This is probably such a beginner question (and it's not homework). I've stumbled upon this:

$$\left(\sqrt{2-\sqrt{3}}\right)^x + \left(\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3}}\right)^x = 2$$

How to solve this equation for $x$? I've tried applying the $\log$ and also
raising the expression to the power of 2, but couldn't go much further. I am probably missing something obvious.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The only real solution is given by $x=0$, since $\sqrt{2-\sqrt{3}}$ and $\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3}}$ are positive real numbers with product one, hence your equation is equivalent to:
$$ e^{cx}+e^{-cx}=2 $$
or:
$$ \cosh(cx) = 1 $$
for $c=\log\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3}}$.

Comment: All of the numbers $2\pi ik/c$ for integral $k$ are also solutions (using your real $c$) if you permit nonreal solutions as well. These comprise the all solutions.

Comment: how would one go about finding 'c'? like what is the general method for translating something to that form?

Comment: @Letseatlunch: what about $u=e^{\log u}$?

Answer (score 10):

HINT :

$$(2-\sqrt 3)^{\frac x2}+(2+\sqrt 3)^{\frac x2}-2=0\iff \left((2-\sqrt 3)^{\frac x4}-(2+\sqrt 3)^{\frac x4}\right)^2=0$$

Comment: Good catch, indeed !

Answer (score 8):

multiply the equation by $(\sqrt{2-\sqrt{3}})^x$
$$(2-\sqrt{3})^x+(\sqrt{4-3})^x=2(\sqrt{2-\sqrt{3}})^x$$
$$(2-\sqrt{3})^x-2(\sqrt{2-\sqrt{3}})^x+1=0$$
$$((2-\sqrt{3})^{x/2})^2-2(2-\sqrt{3})^{x/2}+1=0$$
$$((2-\sqrt{3})^{x/2}-1)^2=0$$
$$(2-\sqrt{3})^{x/2}-1=0$$
$$(2-\sqrt{3})^{x/2}=1$$
take the $\log$
$$x/2\log(2-\sqrt{3})=\log 1$$
hence 
$$x=0$$

Answer (score 4):

since $\sqrt { 2-\sqrt { 3 }  } =\frac { 1 }{ \sqrt { 2+\sqrt { 3 }  }  } $
$t=\left( \sqrt { 2-\sqrt { 3 }  }  \right) ^{ x }$

you should solve only this eqv.
$t+\frac { 1 }{ t } =2$

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

As $(2+\sqrt3)(2-\sqrt3)=1$ set $(2+\sqrt3)^{x/2}=u$ to find $u=1=(2+\sqrt3)^0$

Now as $(2+\sqrt3)^{x/2}=(2+\sqrt3)^0,$

$\implies\dfrac x2=0$ as $2+\sqrt3\ne0,\pm1$

**See also**: [Find all real numbers $x$ for which $\frac{8^x+27^x}{12^x+18^x}=\frac76$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/384090/find-all-real-numbers-x-for-which-frac8x27x12x18x-frac76)