# Solving Equation for $x$

Tags: exponential-function

Solve $(a + \sqrt {a^2 - 1})^{x^2 - 2x} + (a - \sqrt {a^2 - 1})^{x^2 - 2x} - a = 0$ for $x$ , where $a>1$ .

My approach is as follows :
$(a + \sqrt {a^2 - 1})  (a - \sqrt {a^2 - 1})=1 $
Let $(a + \sqrt {a^2 - 1})^{x^2 - 2x}=y$. From here, I got stuck. 

The answer (as given at the back of the book) is $1$, $1 + \sqrt{2}$, $1 - \sqrt{2}$.

Comment: Well, if $(a + \sqrt {a^2 - 1})^{x^2 - 2x}=y$, then what is $(a - \sqrt {a^2 - 1})^{x^2 - 2x}$?

Comment: That would be $\frac{1}{y}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it should be   $(a + \sqrt {a^2 - 1})^{x^2 - 2x} + (a - \sqrt {a^2 - 1})^{x^2 - 2x} - 2a = 0$

So that we have

$$y+\dfrac1y=2a\iff y^2-2ay+1=0$$

$\implies y=\dfrac{2a\pm\sqrt{(2a)^2-4}}2=a\pm\sqrt{a^2-1}$

**Case**$\#1:$ if $y=a+\sqrt{a^2-1},$

$(a+\sqrt{a^2-1})^{x^2-2x}=a+\sqrt{a^2-1}$

Now if $p^x=p^y$

either $x=y$

or $p=1$

or $p=0, x,y>0$

or $p=-1, x-y=$even integer

**Case**$\#2:$ if $y=a-\sqrt{a^2-1},$

$(a+\sqrt{a^2-1})^{x^2-2x}=a-\sqrt{a^2-1}(a+\sqrt{a^2-1})^{-1}$

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/384090/find-all-real-numbers-x-for-which-frac8x27x12x18x-frac76