# solve for $x$: $9^x-6^x=4^{x+1/2}$ (hints only, please)

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$ 9^x-6^x=4^{x+1/2}$, solve for $x$

Please don't solve this problems entirely, I just want some hints. I have tried to substitute $3^x=b$ and $2^x=a$.

Comment: Firstly, posting one problem in one question is enough. You should make an edit. The other two problems can be asked in two separate questions. Secondly, show what you have tried.

Comment: Note: I reformatted your question fairly heavily.  Please check to see that I didn't change your meaning.

Comment: thanks, but I just edited the question to show only 1 problem.

Comment: Ok that is a good start. You should find $(b-2a)(b+a)=0$. You obviously cannot have $a,b$ of opposite signs, so that gives $b=2a$.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/384090/find-all-real-numbers-x-for-which-frac8x27x12x18x-frac76

Comment: Is that $4^\frac{x+1}{2}$ or $4^{x+\frac{1}{2}}$?

Answer (score 2):

Try dividing $9^x $ throughout, and substitute $(\frac {2}{3} )^x $ as $y $.  Also, notice that $\frac {4}{9} = (\frac {2}{3})^2 $.

Comment: Alternatively, divide by $6^x$, you will get an equation involving $\left( \frac 2 3 \right)^x$ and $\left( \frac 3 2 \right)^x$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:   $\ln (y ^x) =x\ln y$. Now you should see the first one.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this:
The equation can be reduced to $$9^x - 6^x = 4^x.4^{1/2}$$ which is $$9^x = 6^x + 2.4^x$$ Now the RHS is divisible by $2$, but the LHS is not, for any values of $x\in \mathbb Z^+$. 
Rest, try using $ln(y^x) = xln(y)$ as others have suggested. That should give the final answer