# Solve equation $4^x-3\cdot6^x+2\cdot9^x=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$4^x-3\cdot6^x+2\cdot9^x=0, x\in\mathbb{R}$

Can someone solve this and explain me step by step cause I have no idea what to do.

Comment: Hint: $s^2-3st+2t^2$.

Comment: Latex advice: don't use $*$ for multiplication. If you really want to put a sign, \cdot works best for $\cdot$.

Comment: See also : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/384090/find-all-real-numbers-x-for-which-frac8x27x12x18x-frac76/384094#384094

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HINT:

See [Exponent Combination Laws](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Exponent_Combination_Laws)

Let $2^x=a,3^x=b$

$\implies 4^x=(2^x)^2=a^2,6^x=ab,9^x=b^2$

Divide both sides of the given equation by $9^x(=b^2)$

Finally  Now if $\displaystyle u^m=1,$

either $\displaystyle m=0,u\ne0; $

or $\displaystyle u=1$

or $\displaystyle u=-1,m$ is even

Comment: great. thanks for help I managed to solve it the solutions I got are: $x_1=0$and $x_2=log_{2/3}{2}$

Answer (score 0):

$$4^x-3\cdot6^x+2\cdot9^x=0$$
$$(2^x)^2-3\cdot 2^x\cdot3^x+2\cdot(3^x)^2=0$$
$$\left(\frac23\right)^{2x}-3\cdot\left(\frac23\right)^{x}+2=0$$
Let $ \left(\frac23 \right)^{x}=t$

$$t^2-3t+2=0$$

$\left(\frac23\right)^{x}=1$ or $\left(\frac23\right)^{x}=2$

$x=0$ or $x=\log_{\frac23}2$

Comment: Taking logarithm  base $2,$   $$x(1-\log_23)=1\iff x=?$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

write the equation as:
$$
2^{2x}-3\cdot 2^x\cdot 3^x+2\cdot 3^{2x}=0 \quad \iff \quad 2^{2x}-2\cdot 2^x\cdot 3^x-1\cdot 2^x\cdot 3^x+2\cdot 3^{2x}=0
$$
that can be factorized as:
$$
\left(2^x-2\cdot 3^x \right)\left(2^x-3^x \right)=0
$$

Now you can solve:
$$
\left(2^x-2\cdot 3^x \right)=0 \quad \lor \quad \left(2^x-3^x \right)=0
$$