# Solving: $4*3^x - 9*2^x = 5* 3^\frac x2 * 2^\frac x2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$4*3^x - 9*2^x = 5* 3^\frac x2 * 2^\frac x2$

I did not understand this equality how to solve it for $x$?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1356236/what-is-the-solution-to-the-equation-9x-6x-2-cdot-4x-0 OR https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1804249/solve-equation-4x-3-cdot6x2-cdot9x-0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$4*3^x - 9*2^x = 5* 3^\frac x2 * 2^\frac x2$$

$$4 - 9*\frac {2^x}{3^x} = 5* \frac {3^\frac x2}{3^x} * 2^\frac x2$$

$$4 - 9*\bigg(\frac  2 3\bigg)^x = 5* \frac{2^\frac x2}{3^\frac x2} $$

Substitute $a=(\frac 23 )^\frac x2$

$$4 - 9a^2 = 5a$$

Solve for a...

$$ 9a^2 +5a-4= 0$$

$$ (a+1)(9a-4)= 0$$

Comment: @user173897 Thanks thats better...

Comment: No problem. You did the hard part. :)

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Solve
$$4m^2-5mn-9n^2=0$$

by factorization.

Notice that $9-4=5$.

Answer (score 0):

$4*3^x - 9*2^x = 5* 3^\frac x2 * 2^\frac x2
$

The right side is
$5\cdot 6^\frac x2
$.

The left side can be factored as

$4*3^x - 9*2^x 
=(2\cdot 3^\frac x2-3\cdot 2^\frac x2)(2\cdot 3^\frac x2+3\cdot 2^\frac x2)
$.

By inspection,
a solution is $x=4$.
($2\cdot 9= 18, 
3\cdot 4 = 12,
(18-12)(18+12)
=6\cdot 30
=5\cdot 6^2$)

The left side is
$3^x(4 - 9*(2/3)^x) 
\le 0
$
for $x \le 2$.
Therefore
$x > 2$.

If
$x \ge 3$,
$4 - 9*(2/3)^x
\ge 4-8/3
=4/3
$
so,
if $x \ge 3$,
$5\cdot 6^\frac x2
\ge (4/3)3^x
$
or
$15/4
\ge (3/2)^{x/2}
$
or
$x \le 2\dfrac{\log(15/4)}{\log(3/2)}
\lt 6.52
$.

Numerically, the only solution is
$x=4$,
and the left side
appears to have
a larger slope than
the right side,
so this would be the only solution.

I will leave it at this.