# Determining the values $a$ can take

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> $$ 9^a + 243 =28\cdot 3^{a+1} $$
>
> Determine the values $a$ can take.

Let us recall that $$3^a =t $$

Then we have

$$t^2 + 3^5 =28\cdot 3t$$

Dividing the both sides by $28$

$$\dfrac{t^2 + 3^5}{28}=3t$$

Here we get two solutions

$$a =\{81,3\}$$

However, I believe that I have gone wrong somewhere.

Comment: These are the solutions for $3^a$ and not for $a$ itself. To get $a$ you need to take the logarithm of your solutions for $t$.

Comment: your solution is correct, despite in the latter expression these are the values for $t$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1804249/solve-equation-4x-3-cdot6x2-cdot9x-0

Answer (score 1):

We have $$9^a+243=28\cdot3^{a+1}\implies (3^a)^2-28\cdot3\cdot3^a+243=0$$ and solve the quadratic for $3^a$ to get $$3^a=81,3.$$ You forgot to do $\log_3$ on both sides.

Answer (score 0):

Your final equation is right but your solution for it is wrong$$t=\dfrac{42\pm\sqrt{42^2-4\cdot 243}}{2}=14\pm 3\sqrt {22}$$where only $14+ 3\sqrt {22}$ is valid ($14-3\sqrt {22}<0$) so we have $$x=\log_3{14+ 3\sqrt {22}}$$

Comment: No; this answer is wrong. Please check again.

Answer (score 0):

$$3^{2a}+3^5=28\cdot 3\cdot3^a$$

$$3^{2a}-84(3^a)+243=0$$
$$y=3^a\to y^2-84y+243=0$$
$$y=81, y=3$$
$$a=\log_3{(y)}\to a=4,1$$