# Equation : $5^{2(x+1)} +621\times{10}^x=100\times4^x$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Find all integer roots of the equation : 
>   $$5^{2(x+1)} +621\times{10}^x=100\times4^x$$

It's easily seen that $x=0$ doesn't work.I feel there's no positive root for this equation but how to proceed?

Comment: Hint: $5^{2x}\cdot5^{2}+621\cdot 5^{2x}=4\cdot 5^{2}\cdot 4^x$

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/384090/find-all-real-numbers-x-for-which-frac8x27x12x18x-frac76

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint :

Divide both sides by $4^x$

$$25\left\{\left(\dfrac52\right)^x\right\}^2+621\left(\dfrac52\right)^x-100=0$$ which is a Quadratic Equation in $\left(\dfrac52\right)^x$

Now if $\displaystyle u^m=1,$

either $\displaystyle m=0,u\ne0; $

or $\displaystyle u=1$

or $\displaystyle u=-1,m$ is even

Comment: But the delta for that new equation isn't a square!

Comment: @HamidRezaEbrahimi, You need to employ logarithm

Comment: I think the equation has to be $25\left\{\left(\dfrac52\right)^x\right\}^2+621\left(\dfrac52\right)^x-100=0$

Comment: You mean we can't solve that using ordinary method for quadratic equations?!

Comment: @Curious, Thanks for your observation

Comment: @HamidRezaEbrahimi, Please fidn the updated answer

Comment: @labbhattacharjee Now it's easily solved,thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

If $x\ge1$, the left hand side of $5^{2(x+1)}+621\times10^x=100\times4^x$ is odd while the right hand side is even, which is impossible, so we must have $x\le0$.  Writing $x=-u$, and multiplying both sides by $2^{2u}\times5^{2u}$ to make all the powers non-negative, the equation becomes

$$5^2\times2^{2u}+621\times10^u=2^2\times5^{2+2u}$$

or

$$621\times10^u=5^2(2^2\times5^{2u}-2^{2u})$$

The right hand side is divisible by $5^2$ but by no higher power of $5$.  So $u=2$ is the only possible integer solution.  And, indeed, $5^2(2^2\times5^4-2^4)=10^2(5^4-2^2)=10^2(625-4)=621\times10^2$.  Thus $x=-2$ is the sole integer solution.