# Solve $2^x+4^x=2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponential-function, quadratics

This is the equation, but the result is different from wolframalpha:

$$2^x+4^x=2$$
$$2^x+2^{2x}=2^1$$
$$x+2x=1$$
$$x=\frac{1}{3}$$

WolframAlpha: $x=0$

Where is the error?

Comment: The error is in the step $2^x+2^{2x}=2^1\implies x+2x=1$ which is not true. You can't just take out the exponents this way.

Comment: To do this question, let $u=2^x$. Then, $4^x=(2^x)^2=u^2$. Then, the equation becomes $u+u^2=2$, which is a quadratic equation.

Comment: why not? Aren't them in the same base?

Comment: If there is only one term, i.e. $2^m=2^n$, then you can say $m=n$. The principle is by taking the log of both sides, i.e. $\log_2(2^m)=\log_2(2^n)$.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1827123/equation-52x1-621-times10x-100-times4x?lq=1 OR  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1804249/solve-equation-4x-3-cdot6x2-cdot9x-0?lq=1

Comment: However, if you have the form $2^a+2^b=2^c$, then when you try to take the log of both sides, you would get $\log_2(2^a+2^b)=c$, but $\log_2(2^a+2^b)\ne\log_2(2^a)+\log_2(2^b)$

Comment: $2^x\cdot 2^{2x}=2^1$ implies that $x+2x=1$. Exponentiation turns a sum to a product (and contrariwise taking logarithms turns a product into a sum). There is no formula for $\log(a+b)$ in general.

Comment: ok, with substitution I get $u_1=1$ and $u_2=-2$

Comment: Then $2^{x_1}=1$ and $2^{x_2}=-2$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$$2^x+2^{2x}=2$$

Now put $2^x=t$

$$t+t^{2}=2$$

$$t^{2}+t-2=0$$

$$(t-1)(t+2)=0$$

Thus $t=1$ or $t=-2$

$2^x=1$ or $2^x=-2$

Since $2^x>0 $ for all real $x$ , $2^x=1=2^0$

Therefore $x=0$

Answer (score 2):

$a^x \cdot a^y=a^{x+y}$ is the identity 
you are using $a^x+a^y=a^{x+y}$ which is not correct

Answer (score 2):

$2^x + 4^x= 2$ $\Rightarrow$ $2^x (1 + 2^x ) = 2$  $\Rightarrow $ $1 + 2^x = 2 ^{1 - x}$ $\Rightarrow$ $1 + 2^x = 2 ^{- x} \times 2$

Now Set $ y = 2^x$; then we have

$1 + y = y^{-1} \times 2 $ $\Rightarrow$ $y^2 + y -2 = 0$. Which has solutions $y = 1$ and $y = -2$.

$y = -2 $ is unacceptable, because $y = 2^x$ is a positive function. So $y = 2^x = 0$ is acceptable and will give us $ x = 0$. And we are done!

Answer (score 1):

we have $$2^{2x}+2^x-2=0$$ and with $$2^x=t$$ you will get $$t^2+t-2=0$$ a quadratic equation to solve.