# Please help to find the solution

Tags: quadratics

$$2^{x-2} + 2^{3-x} = 3$$
Please find the value of $x$ and give the solution process.

Comment: Hint: Multiply both sides by $2^x$. Have a try!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$2^{x-2} + 2^{3-x}= 3 $ $ \iff $

$ 2^{x} *  \frac{1}{4}  + 8*2^{-x} = 3  $  $ \iff  (2^{x})^{2} *  \frac{1}{4}-3*2^{-x} + 8 = 0    $ we put $2^{x}=y$ we have,  $ \frac{1}{4}y²-3y+8=0 \iff y=4 $ or $ y=8 $ now you can find easily that $ x=2 $ and $ x=3 $

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

$$3=\dfrac y{2^2}+\dfrac{2^3}y$$  where $2^x=y$

Now multiply both sides by $y(\ne0)$ for finite $x$

Comment: See also : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/384090/find-all-real-numbers-x-for-which-frac8x27x12x18x-frac76