# How can i solve $5^{2x-\frac{1}{3}x^2} < 5^{2-2x} * (5^\frac{1}{3})^{x^2}+24$?

Tags: inequality

How can i solve it?

$$5^{2x-\frac{1}{3}x^2} < 5^{2-2x} * (5^\frac{1}{3})^{x^2}+24$$

I don't have idea how to solve it..

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2570576/how-can-i-solve-this-42x-15-4x2-16x2-fracx2-0

Comment: I asked it, but i don't understand how to solve it according to the older exercise.

Comment: Rearrange to form a quadratic equation like the linked answer. Now $$(x-a)(x-b)<0\implies a<x<b$$

Comment: Put $A=5^{2x-x^2/3}$. Then the inequality is the same as $A<5^2/A+24$, or $\frac{(A-25)(A+1)}{A}<0$. You get that $A=5^{2x-x^2/3}$ must be either on $(-\infty,-1)$ or in $(0,25)$. $A$ cannot be negative, therefore it is in $(0,25)$. Take logarithms base $5$ to conclude that $2x-x^2/3<2$. Factor, and solve.

Comment: @ uldek, you should post this as an answer, not a comment. Then we can up vote your solution.

Comment: @uldek The fact remains, that kind of statement belongs in an answer, not in a comment. You have a habit of answering questions in comments, I've noticed. See the [guidelines](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) for commenting if you need any further clarification on the matter.

Comment: " I am not interested in your vote. It means nothing to me."  And we are not interested in your desires and wishes.  They mean nothing to us.  We want the questioned answered.

Answer (score 2):

Taking uldek's comment in the form of an answer.

Let $A=5^{2x-{x^2}/3}$. Note that $A>0$ for any $x$.

> Notice that A appears as is on the LHS.
>
> Notice that A is hidden on the RHS, as $5^{2-2x}*(5^{1/3})^{x^2}=5^2*5^{-2x+{x^2}/3}=5^2*A^{-1}$.

Now the inequality is $A < 25*A^{-1} +24$;

> Take all the terms on the same side:

$A -24 - 25*A^{-1} < 0$

> As $A>0$, you can multiply both sides by A without changing the sense of the inequality:

$A^2 - 24A - 25 < 0$

> Factor:

$(A-25)(A+1)<0$

> Draw a little table where you show the sign of the product:

$$
\begin{array}{c|ccc}
A & \text{under -1} & \text{between} & \text{over 25} \\
\hline
A+1 & - & + & + \\
A-25 & - & - & + \\
(A-25)(A+1) & + & - & + \\
\end{array}
$$

> So, that the inequation is negative implies $-1<A<25$
>
> Remember that $A>0$ no matter what, so we solve:

$0<A<25$
$5^{2x-{x^2}/3}<25$

> We notice that $25=5^2$

$5^{2x-{x^2}/3}<5^2$

> By definition of what $5^r$ is (that is : $5^r=e^{r*ln(5)}$), and the exponential function being a strictly increasing function, so $e^X<e^Y$ is equivalent to $X<Y$.
>   Put another way, "you take the logarithm" of the inequality - logarithm being also a strictly increasing function.

$2x-{x^2}/3<2$

> Put all the terms on the same side of the inequality (this time, I am choosing the right hand side):

${x^2}/3-2x+2>0$

> Multiplying by 3 > 0 keeps the sense of the inequality:

${x^2}-6x+6>0$

> Factor... yes, discuss $b^2-4ac$, that stuff...

$(x-(3+\sqrt{3}))(x-(3-\sqrt{3}))>0$

> Discuss the sign of the product...

$$
\begin{array}{c|ccc}
x & \text{under $3-\sqrt{3}$} & \text{between} & \text{over $3+\sqrt{3}$} \\
\hline
x-(3-\sqrt{3}) & - & + & + \\
x-(3+\sqrt{3}) & - & - & + \\
(x-(3+\sqrt{3}))(x-(3-\sqrt{3})) & + & - & + \\
\end{array}
$$

> You can now write down the conclusion.

**Hope this helps!**

*(and I hope that no typo sneaked in my text)*

Answer (score 1):

We have,

$$5^{2x-\frac{1}{3}x^2} < 5^{2-2x} * (5^\frac{1}{3})^{x^2}+24$$

$$5^{2x-\frac{1}{3}x^2} - 5^{2-2x} \cdot (5^\frac{1}{3})^{x^2}- 24<0 $$

$$5^{2x-\frac{1}{3}x^2} - 5^{2-2x + \frac{1}{3} x^2 } - 24 < 0 $$

Substitute $ 5^{2x - \frac{1}{3}x^2} = t $,

$$t - \frac{5^2}{t} - 24 < 0 $$

$$\frac{(t-25)(t+1)}{t} < 0 $$

$$ t \in (-∞,-1) \cup (0,25) $$
Since $ t$ is a constant raised to some exponent , it can't be negative.

So, $$ t \in (0,25) $$

Which implies,

$$5^{2x-\frac{1}{3}x^2} < 25 $$
To get $x$ taking logarithm with base as $5$,

$$\log_5{5^{2x-\frac{1}{3}x^2} } < \log_5 {5^2} $$

$$ 2x- \frac{1}{3}x^2 < 2 $$

$$ - \frac{1}{3}x^2 + 2x -3 < 0  $$

$$ \frac{1}{3}x^2 -2x + 3 > 0  $$

$$ x^2- 6x + 6 > 0  $$

$$ x = 3+√3, x= 3-√3 $$