# Indices Question & Equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponentiation

Following is the equation

$$x^{x\sqrt x}=x\sqrt{x}$$

We need to find $x$.
Please help.

Comment: We have $$x^{x^{1+1/2}}=x^{3/2}$$

Comment: $$x=1$$ is one solution.

Comment: $x=0$ is, amazingly, *not* a solution.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 4):

**HINT**

Take logs to get
$$
x\sqrt{x} \ln x = \ln x + \frac12 \ln x \\
\ln x \left(x \sqrt{x} - \frac32\right) = 0
$$

Can you finish?

Comment: @user541396 usually one thinks of $0^0$ as undefined

Answer (score 0):

What if $x=0$?

For finite non-zero $x,$

$$x^{x^{3/2}-3/2}=1$$

From [Find all real numbers $x$ for which $\frac{8^x+27^x}{12^x+18^x}=\frac76$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/384090/find-all-real-numbers-x-for-which-frac8x27x12x18x-frac76/384094#384094), check if $u^m=1$