# Exponential systems of equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

I'm preparing for uni entrance exam. I've been struggling with this problem for about 90 minutes, tried everything I could think of. Can anybody explain how to solve this step by step?

$$x^{x+y}\:=\:y^{12},\:y^{x+y}=x^3$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First taking the log of both sides of both equations and isolating $x+y$
$$x^{x+y}\:=\:y^{12},\:y^{x+y}=x^3
\\ \implies x+y = 12 \frac{log(y)  }{log(x)}=3 \frac{log(x)  }{log(y)}$$

Now let $z \equiv \frac{log(x)  }{log(y)}$
so the last equation becomes 
$$ \frac{12}z=3z \implies z=\pm2$$
so $$ x = y^{\pm 2}$$
plugging $ x = y^{ 2}$into the original equations gives

$$ y^{2(x+y)} = y^{12} \text{ and } y^{x+y}=y^6  \implies x+y=6$$
SInce $ x = y^{ 2}$ we have ...
$$y^2+y=6
\implies (y+3)(y-2)=0$$

Which gives us two solutions for $(x,y)$, namely $(9,-3)$ and $(4,2)$

If we consider $x=y^{-2}$ we get $y^2+y=-6$ which has no real solutions.

So it looks like the only two solutions are $(9,-3)$ and $(4,2)$

Comment: how about $$x=y=1?$$

Comment: OK - so the complete set of solutions is $\{ (9,-3), (4,2) , (1,1), (1, -1) \}$ and perhaps $(0,0)$

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that $x,y >0$, $(x+y)\log\, x =12 \log\, y$ and $(x+y) \log\, y=3\log\, x$. Dividing one by the other we get $\frac {log\, x} {log\, y}=4 \frac {log\, y} {log\, x}$ which gives $\frac {log\, x} {log\, y}=\pm 2$.  Now use the first equation to get $x+y=\pm 6$. Since $x,y>0$ we must have $x+y=6$ and $\frac {log\, x} {log\, y}= 2$. This gives $x+y=6$ and $x=y^{2}$. I leave the rest to you.

Comment: Powers of negative numbers involve complex numbers and they are not even single valued. So it is reasonable to assume that $x$ and $y$ are positive. BTW the answer is $x=4$ and $y=2$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint

$$x^3=y^{x+y}$$

$$(x^3)^{12}=(x^{x+y})^{x+y}$$

Either $x=1$

Or $x=-1$ and $36-(x+y)^2$ is even

Or $36-(x+y)^2=0$

Or $x=0$ and $(x+y)^2\ge0$ which holds true for all real $y$

Plug the values of $x$ in $$y^{12}=x^{x+y}$$

**See also** :  [Find all real numbers $x$ for which $\frac{8^x+27^x}{12^x+18^x}=\frac76$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/384090/find-all-real-numbers-x-for-which-frac8x27x12x18x-frac76/384094#384094)