# Given that $9^{2x} = 27^{x^2 - 5}$. Find the possible values of $x$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponentiation

Given that $9^{2x} = 27^{x^2 - 5}$. Find the possible values of $x$.

I don't know how to approach this question.

Comment: Just rewrite this as $3^{f(x)}=3^{g(x)}$.

Comment: Thank You very much!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hints**:

1. $9=3^2$
2. $27=3^3$
3. $(a^b)^c = a^{bc}$
4. $a^x = a^y$ if and only if $x=y$.

Comment: (+1) Perfect hints. Now, xx_Gcsemathstudent_xx it's your turn.

Comment: $4x = 3x^2 - 15$ so 0 = $3x^2 - 4x - 15$

Comment: Now I can solve for x

Comment: @xx_Gcsemathstudent_xx Exactly!

Comment: Tyy very much for helping!

Comment: @xx_Gcsemathstudent_xx Don't forget to upvote all helpful answers and accept the best one.

Comment: I have to wait 4 minutes

Answer (score 3):

Using that $$3^{4x}=3^{3x^2-15}$$ we get the equation $$4x=3x^2-15$$

Comment: Thank You very much!

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:

We have
\begin{align}
9^{2x} = 27^{x^2 - 5} &\iff \exp(\ln(9)2x) = \exp(\ln(27)(x^2-5))\\
&\iff \frac{\ln(9)}{\ln(27)}2x -x^2 + 5=0
\end{align}

Comment: Thank You very much!

Comment: @xx_Gcsemathstudent_xx You're welcome ;)

Answer (score 2):

As $9=3^2, 9^{2x}=(3^2)^{2x}=3^{4x}$

Similarly, $27^{x^2-5}=3^{3x^2-15}$

As $3^{4x}\ne0,$

$$\implies1=\dfrac{3^{3x^2-15}}{3^{4x}}=3^{3x^2-4x-15}$$

Now like [Find all real numbers $x$ for which $\frac{8^x+27^x}{12^x+18^x}=\frac76$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/384090/find-all-real-numbers-x-for-which-frac8x27x12x18x-frac76/384094#384094),

if $\displaystyle u^m=1,$

either $\displaystyle m=0 $

or $\displaystyle u=1$

or $\displaystyle u=-1,m$ is even

But here $u=3\ne\pm1$

Answer (score 1):

Hints$$9 = 3^2 \implies 9^z = 3^{2z} $$
$$27 = 3^3 \implies 27^y = 3^{3y}$$

Now compare both sides.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: You're welcome!