# Solve for $x$, $(1+2i)^{(2x+6)}=(-11-2i)^{(x+1)} $

Tags: complex-numbers

$$(1+2i)^{(2x+6)}=(-11-2i)^{(x+1)} $$

Solve for $x$

My Work:

Take ln at the both sides:

$$(2x+6)\ln(1+2i)=(x+1)\ln(-11-2i)$$
and$$\ln(1+2i)=\ln(\sqrt{5})+i\arctan(2)$$
$$\ln(-11-2i)=\ln(5\sqrt{5})+i\left[\arctan\left(\frac{2}{11}\right)+\pi\right]\\=\ln(5)+\ln(\sqrt{5})+i\left[\arctan\left(\frac{2}{11}\right)+\pi\right]$$

And things get dirty here because of $\arctan$ and $\ln$ ...

But
$$(2x+6)\ln(1+2i)=(x+1)\ln(-11-2i)$$ from here

$$2x+6=(x+1)\dfrac{\ln(-11-2i)}{\ln(1+2i)}$$

then

$$x\left(2-\dfrac{\ln(-11-2i)}{\ln(1+2i)}\right)=-6+\dfrac{\ln(-11-2i)}{\ln(1+2i)}$$

then

$$x=\dfrac{-6+\dfrac{\ln(-11-2i)}{\ln(1+2i)}}{2-\dfrac{\ln(-11-2i)}{\ln(1+2i)}}$$

But specifically I cannot find x here.

Any elegant way to solve it, or not elegant but proper, any hint any help, would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Logarithms and powers of complex numbers are not uniquely defined and your formula is not valid.

Comment: How about you just take the modulus?

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Observe that $11^2+2^2=\cdots=5^3, 5=1^2+2^2$

which encouraged me  to find $$(1+2i)^3=1-12+(6-8)i$$

$$\implies(-11-2i)^{(x+1)}=((1+2i)^3)^{x+1}=?$$

So we have $$(1+2i)^{3(x+1)-(2x+6)}=1$$

Taking logarithm in both sides, $$(x-3)\ln(1+2i)=2n\pi i$$ where $n$ is any integer

Now $1+2i=\sqrt{1^2+2^2}\cdot e^{i\arctan2}$

$\implies\ln(1+2i)=\dfrac{\ln5}2+i\arctan2+2m\pi i$  where $m$ is any integer

**See also**: [Find all real numbers $x$ for which $\frac{8^x+27^x}{12^x+18^x}=\frac76$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/384090/find-all-real-numbers-x-for-which-frac8x27x12x18x-frac76/384094#384094)

Comment: Logarithms and powers of complex numbers are not uniquely defined and your answer is not valid.

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy, but it will still give one of the solution?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy, I'd just supplied hint to start with. Now I have supplied the exhaustive solution

Answer (score 0):

$$(1+2i)^{(2x+6)}=(-11-2i)^{(x+1)}$$ is equivalent to $$(1+2i)^{(2x+6)}=(1+2i)^{3(x+1)}$$ or, assuming $(1+2i)^{(2x+3)}\neq 0,$ $$(1+2i)^{3}=(1+2i)^{x}.$$
One solution is $x=3.$

I do not think that other solutions would be trivial to find.