# Logarithm Question Solution

Tags: logarithms

How do I solve this question?
$$25^{\left(2x-x^2+1\right)}+9^{\left(2x-x^2+1\right)}=34\left(15^{2x-x^2}\right)$$
I tried splitting 15 to 5 and 3 and writing 25 and 9 as the squares of 5 and 3. I got stuck after that, could anyone please help me?

Comment: I see one obvious solution.

Comment: Could you please guide me? Like, at least just type out what I should do?

Comment: Try $x=0$. ${}{}$

Comment: In the exponent of the rhs, add and subract $1$

Comment: Oh, yeah got it. Thanks. @Claude Leibovici

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your way of splitting works.

Set $u=x(2-x)\leq 1$ and divide by $15^u = 3^u5^u$. So, you get

$$25t + 9\frac 1t = 34 \text{ with } t= \left(\frac 53\right)^u$$

Solving for $t>0$ gives

$$t= 1 \Rightarrow u=0 \Rightarrow x=0, x=2$$

and

$$t= \frac 9{25} \Rightarrow u=-2 \Rightarrow x=1+\sqrt 3, x=1-\sqrt 3$$

Answer (score 5):

Hint:

Let $5^{2x-x^2}=a,3^{2x-x^2}=b$

$$0=25a^2-34ab+9b^2=25a(a-b)-9b(a-b)=?$$

**Case**$\#1$:  If $25a=9b,$

$\iff\dfrac{25}9=\dfrac ba$

$\iff\left(\dfrac35\right)^{-2}=\left(\dfrac35\right)^{2x-x^2}\iff\left(\dfrac35\right)^{x^2-2x-2}=1$

Use [Find all real numbers $x$ for which $\frac{8^x+27^x}{12^x+18^x}=\frac76$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/384090/find-all-real-numbers-x-for-which-frac8x27x12x18x-frac76/384094#384094)

**Case**$\#2$:
What if $a=b?$

Answer (score 0):

As @TickaJules pointed out there is one obvious solution.  let $\alpha = 2x-x^2$ and rewrite the equation
$$
25*25^{\alpha}+ 9*9^{\alpha}=34*15^{\alpha}
$$
Since $25 + 9=34$ then clearly $\alpha =0$ solves the equation with $x=2$