Solving a logarithmic equation with different logarithmic exponents.
I had a logarithmic equation which originally was
original
https://i.sstatic.net/2fSf1jNM.png
$$5^{\log_{10}x}-3^{\log_{10}x-1}=3^{\log_{10}x+1}-5^{\log_{10}x-1}$$
but I thought that this should also have a solution.
modified
https://i.sstatic.net/oVIdMbA4.png
$$5^{\log_{10}x}-3^{\log_{10}(x-1)}=3^{\log_{10}(x+1)}-5^{\log_{10}(x-1)}$$
I am in grade 11 so I don't know a lot about logarithms but I have a basic knowledge.
Please help If you can,I have tried to ask my teachers this but they have also failed to solve it.

have a look at mathjax for your mathematical expressions.

@Divyanshundley: The first has an integer solution $x = 100$, but the second requires numerical methods for $x = 2.12627$.

Yeah,But can you name some or provide some hints so that I can solve?

Hint:
$$5^{\log_{10}x-1}(5+1)=3^{\log_{10}x-1}(3^2+1)$$
$$\iff\left(\dfrac53\right)^{\log_{10}x-2}=1\implies \log_{10}x=2\iff x=10^2$$

See also : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/384090/find-all-real-numbers-x-for-which-frac8x27x12x18x-frac76/384094#384094

this is the solution for the first one which is easy but the second one is not so much.

@Divyanshundley,     $$5^{\log_{10}x-1}(5+1)-3^{\log_{10}x-1}(3^2+1)$$ is an increasing function, right?  So, how can it admit   non-unique solutions?

no I am talking about the modified version of the equation.
